# Swift timer won't work after invalidating and reinitiating

Tags: ios, swift, timer, nstimer

I'm using Timer() for indicating current audio position in audio player

```
func startTimer() {
        print("PlayerController: startTimer()")
        if itemPlayTimer != nil {
            return
        }
        itemPlayTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.001,
                                                  target: self,
                                                  selector: #selector(updateItemPlayerTimer),
                                                  userInfo: nil,
                                                  repeats: true)
    }

 @objc func updateItemPlayerTimer() {
        guard let currentTime = player?.currentTime else {
            return
        }
        updateTimeDescription?(currentTime)
    }
```

when user pause player app invalidating timer

```
func stopTimer() {
        itemPlayTimer?.invalidate()
        itemPlayTimer = nil
    }
```

But after calling startTimer() again selector won't call

Comment: try this, Timer(timeInterval: 0.001, target: self, selector: #selector(updateItemPlayerTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

Comment: Try to increase some time from 0.001 to 0.1

Comment: it's still doesn't work. At the second time method startTimer() is calling, timer initiating, but selector doesn't call

Comment: when you are calling start timer again ? and also check your player?.currentTime is nil or not when second time selector fires

Comment: check this answer for implementing timer properly
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34509335/7698092

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason was that the timer starts executing in other thread, not in main thread.

Comment: How did you found out ?

Comment: I put timer start code to Dispatch.Queue.main{ } directly and it's work, then i found part of code where start timer code calling in extra queue and fix it

Answer (score 0):

change your functions in this way:

```
func startTimer() {
        print("PlayerController: startTimer()")
        if itemPlayTimer == nil {
            itemPlayTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.001,
                                                  target: self,
                                                  selector: #selector(updateItemPlayerTimer),
                                                  userInfo: nil,
                                                  repeats: true)
        }

}

@objc func updateItemPlayerTimer() {
    guard let currentTime = player?.currentTime else {
        return
    }
    updateTimeDescription?(currentTime)
}

func stopTimer() {
    if itemPlayTimer != nil {
        itemPlayTimer?.invalidate()
        itemPlayTimer = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it's still doesn't work...
At the second time method startTimer() is calling, timer initiating, but selector doesn't call

Comment: then it should works fine, check your player if it be nil or not

Comment: player is ok, audio is playing, but the audio progress is frozen

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code. I have used An **AVPlayer** with a sample Video to demonstrate pausing/playing with Timer. Logic is same for audio player.
Just replace AVPlayer with your audioPlayer.

Key logic here is to properly manage the state of Playing/not playing and checking timer for nil etc.

As indicated in this [**Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34509335/7698092)

> startTimer() starts the timer only if it's nil and stopTimer() stops
>   it only if it's not nil.
>
> You have only to take care of stopping the timer before
>   creating/starting a new one.

I have **implemented** this in a sample project and is **working 100%**.

- Carefully See the function **pauseTapped(_  sender: UIButton)**
- See sample gif At end of Code

---

```
import UIKit
import AVKit

class TimerVC: UIViewController {

  ///A container view for displaying the AVPlayer.
  @IBOutlet weak var playerView: UIView!
  /// A button to play and pause the video
  @IBOutlet weak var btnPause: UIButton!

  ///to maintain the status of AVPlayer playing or not
  var flagPlaying = true
  ///An AVPlayer for displaying and playing the video
  var player: AVPlayer?
  ///to show the current time to user
  @IBOutlet weak var lblCurrentTime: UILabel!

  override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    //add an AVPlayer with sample URL link
    addVideoPlayer( playerView: playerView)

  }
  ///Timer
  var itemPlayTimer: Timer?
  @objc func startTimer() {

    if itemPlayTimer != nil {
      return
    }
    itemPlayTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.001,
                                         target: self,
                                         selector: #selector(updateItemPlayerTimer),
                                         userInfo: nil,
                                         repeats: true)
  }

  ///update time label
  @objc func updateItemPlayerTimer() {
    guard let currentTime = player?.currentTime else {
      return
    }

    updateTimeDescription(currentTime())
  }

  func updateTimeDescription( _ currentTime :CMTime ) {
    self.lblCurrentTime.text = "\(currentTime.seconds)"
  }

  ///To Pause and play the video
  @IBAction func pauseTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if flagPlaying {
      //pause
      if itemPlayTimer != nil {
        player?.pause()
        itemPlayTimer?.invalidate()
        itemPlayTimer = nil
        flagPlaying = false

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self.btnPause.setTitle("Play", for: .normal)
        }

      }

    }else {
      //not playing
      if itemPlayTimer == nil {
        player?.play()
        startTimer()

        flagPlaying = true
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self.btnPause.setTitle("Pause", for: .normal)
        }

      }

    }

  }

  private func addVideoPlayer(playerView: UIView) {

    //let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
    player = AVPlayer.init(url: URL.init(string: "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4")!)


    let layer: AVPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    layer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: playerView.frame.width, height: playerView.frame.height)
    layer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
    playerView.layer.sublayers?.forEach({$0.removeFromSuperlayer()})
    playerView.layer.addSublayer(layer)

    flagPlaying = true
    player?.play()
    startTimer()
  }


}
```

---

### Working Example

[image: Working example]

Let me know if you need any help

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but for me it's still doesn't work properly